# Layout Issue when Reordering SwiftUI Lists on macOS

Tags: swift, list, macos, swiftui

When reordering a SwiftUI `List` using drag/drop on macOS, which **does not** use `SidebarListStyle`, a large amount of blank space appears underneath the row that has been moved.

This doesn't happen on iOS or if the list style is set to `SidebarListStyle`.

[image]

Here's example code that shows the problem.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = [
        Item(title:"Number 1"),
        Item(title:"Number 2"),
        Item(title:"Number 3"),
        Item(title:"Number 4"),
        Item(title:"Number 5"),
        Item(title:"Number 6"),
        Item(title:"Number 7"),
        Item(title:"Number 8"),
        Item(title:"Number 9"),
        Item(title:"Number 10")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                Text(item.title)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            }
            .onMove { (indexSet, index) in
                self.items.move(fromOffsets: indexSet, toOffset: index)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Is there any way to prevent this extra space from appearing?

Comment: I opened a developer technical support (DTS) ticket with Apple and created a bug in their Feedback system. I got the following response: "There is no workaround; it is still under investigation." That was on February 2, haven't heard anything further since.

Comment: This is still broken as of macOS Big Sur 11.3 Beta (20E5231a)

Answer (score 0):

Nasty and ugly<sup>1</sup> but acceptable workaround for the time being:

```swift
self.items.move(fromOffsets: indexSet, toOffset: index)
let container = self.items
self.items.removeAll()
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.items = container
}
```

<sup>1</sup>Causing some flickering on mouse drop due to list reload